# Restore toolbar bookmarks

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, export, import, toolbar

Currently I have some bookmarks in the bookmarks toolbar. If I export the
bookmarks to HTML, then import them, they do not get added to the bookmarks
toolbar.

Instead, they are added as a sub-menu in bookmarks. How can I export/import such
that the toolbar bookmarks are restored properly?

Comment: Instead of exporting the bookmarks to an HTML file, initiate a [manual backup](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them#w_backup-and-restore) in the `.json` file format.  However, please note the warning within that Mozilla support article:  *Caution: Restoring bookmarks from a backup will overwrite your current set of bookmarks with the ones in the backup file.*  In other words, this method will definitely achieve your goal but it also restores a snapshot of **every** bookmark to where they were at the time the backup file was created.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?